# Identificar produto pelo código de barras

Tags: android

Boa Tarde, 
Estou em um início de um projeto. Este consiste em ler o código de barras e identificar pelo menos as características principais do produto, como nome, marca e foto ilustrativa. Em algumas pesquisas e testes que fiz notei que ao identificar o código de barras e pesquisá-lo no google em quase 100% dos obtenho tais características com sucesso. Como posso absorvê-las para minha aplicação?

Comment: Para leitura de código de barra, utilize uma `library`: https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner  |  Para pesquisa no Google, utilize a API Custom Search by Google

Comment: Obrigado, já me mostrou um caminho. Estou pesquisando um pouco mais aqui e aos poucos entendendo como funcionará.